# Bootstrap 3: Nested tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put a tab inside of a tab, but whenever I click a inner nested tab, the entire inner nested tab row goes away. Here is an example in a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jNWMY/1/

Try clicking "Acquisitions/Facebook" tab. You will notice the second row of tabs just disappear.

Here is my code

```
<h1> Dashboard </h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_tabs">
    <li><a href="#acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Acquisition</b> <span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#engagement_tab" data-toggle="tab">Engagement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#retention_tab" data-toggle="tab">Retention</a></li>
    <li><a href="#revenue_tab" data-toggle="tab">Revenue</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_tabs">
            <li><a href="#all_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>All</b> <span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#facebook_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Facebook</b> <span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></a></li>
            <li><a href="#yahoo_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Yahoo</b> <span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="engagement_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> Engagement tab </p>
    </div>

    <div id="retention_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> Retention tab </p>
    </div>

    <div id="revenue_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> Revenue tab </p>
    </div>

    <div id="all_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> All acquisition </p>
    </div>  

    <div id="facebook_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> All acquisition </p>
    </div>

    <div id="yahoo_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p> All acquisition </p>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Your inner tabs should be wrapped in a div with the `tab-content` class.**

Try this...

```
<h1> Dashboard </h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_tabs">
    <li><a href="#acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Acquisition</b> <span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#engagement_tab" data-toggle="tab">Engagement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#retention_tab" data-toggle="tab">Retention</a></li>
    <li><a href="#revenue_tab" data-toggle="tab">Revenue</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_tabs">
            <li><a href="#all_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>All</b><span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#facebook_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Facebook</b><span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></a></li>
            <li><a href="#yahoo_acquisition_tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Yahoo</b><span style="color:red">(-30%)</span> <br> Total Installs</a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="engagement_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Engagement tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="retention_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Retention tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="revenue_tab" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Revenue tab</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="all_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
            <p>All acquisition</p>
        </div>
        <div id="facebook_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
            <p>All acquisition</p>
        </div>
        <div id="yahoo_acquisition_tab" class="tab-pane">
            <p>All acquisition</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should there be two elements with the same id: "dashboard_tabs" ? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id