# Bootstrap tab is working but the tab content is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js

I am working on admin dashboard with html, css and javascripts. This is my first time working on it. I used bootstrap for the responsive layout and some bootstrap js (tabs, collaps). I also use chartjs for pie chart and line chart and sidr responsive menu. But the problem is with bootstrap tab and collaps function. They didn't work properly.When i click on the tab menu tabs are working but don't showing chart content in it. I spent lot of time to fix this. But i can't. I need your help.

Here is the link for the admin dashboard: http://demo.devkinz.com/admindashboard/

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: Nested tabs also need the tab-content wrapper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531624/bootstrap-3-nested-tab

Comment: weekly and monthly work, usage and monthly don't work - they are nested put a .tab-content around those too

Comment: Really excellent work, btw.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pewag/1/edit

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable comment. But unfortunately i didn't found my ans.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the JavaScript, but aren't targeting the tab elements with it. From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), you also need to add in a bit of JavaScript to specifically target those tabs.

Alternatively, you should be able to add `data-toggle="tab"` to each of your `dashboard_menu li` elements.

Comment: Sorry... i am not talking about dashboard_menu li
I am talking about the graph which have two tab button (Weekly and Monthly). 
Thnx for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#ussgemonth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Usage</a></li>
  <li><a href="#coletsmonth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>
</ul>
```

*But you have no `.tab-pane`'s with the id's: id="ussgemonth" & id="coletsmonth"*

Not only do you have 2 missing `.tab-pane` with these ids -- since these are nested you have to follow the same structure as the parent.

Comment: I put '.tab-pane' class after '.tab-content' .
I think my tab is working but the content in tab which is made by chart.js is not working.

Sorry if i bother you. 
Thanks for you reply.